# protected inheritance

Tags: c++

Why protected and private inheritance are defined and proposed? I understand some cases private inheritance could be used but it is not recommended. How about protected inheritance?

Can anyone offer me an situation in which protected inheritance is a choice?

I rarely see this.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Private inheritance is usually used for mixins---where people inherit to get functionality from the base class, rather than because of "is-a" inheritance.

Protected inheritance can also be used for mixins, where the mixed-in functionality is to be available to downstream classes too.

Comment: can you give me an example of protected inheritance, for example, for private inheritance, car private inherited from engine is usually used.

Comment: Car `has-a` engine. So ideally `composition` should be used and not `inheritance`. Generally one should use inheritance when the relationship is `is-a`. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @Gautam: While in many cases composition is more ideal for has-a, in some cases, non-public inheritance can be used instead. Of course, public inheritance must model is-a.

Comment: Private inheritance is used to specify an `as-a` relationship, as in you implement a foo `as-a` bar. So a queue might privately inherit from a linked list class. Nothing outside the queue class knows how it was implemented, but the queue class can be written like it is a linked_list, which I guess could be nicer syntax wise than composition, but they would accomplish the same goals. I would avoid saying something like a car privately inherits from an engine. While it would probably work, it's confusing and makes much more sense to make the engine a member.

Answer (score 5):

I generally don't use `protected` inheritance.  In fact, I don't generally use `private` inheritance.  If something does not satisfy the Liskov Substitution Principle then I don't see a reason to use inheritance of any kind; and if it does satisfy LSP then you use `public` inheritance.

However, the language distinguishes between `private` and `protected` only from the class's point of view (that is, code using the class can't tell the difference).

You should use `protected` inheritance when you [want it's semantics](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/private-inheritance#prot-vs-priv-inherit), and you should use `private` when you don't want `protected`.

Comment: If something uses private inheritance, then from the POV of non-friends, it doesn't inherit from the base and hence certainly doesn't satisfy LSP. Private inheritance is for when the inheritance is an implementation detail, not part of the public interface. So perhaps it *could* satisfy LSP, perhaps not, but either way you don't want it to.

Comment: Link says access is denied.

Comment: Thanks for the report about the link; I've pointed the link at the semi-official C++ Super FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

See Herb Sutter's [Uses and Abuses of Inheritance, Part 1](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill06.htm), which is also in his [More Exceptional C++](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mxc++.htm) book.

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation i would use Protected inheritance

Base -> Derived1 -> Derived2

- I dont want Derived1 to be substituted for the Base class
- I want to use functionality in base and also allow the Derived2 to use it without exposing 
  the functionality to client classes

Comment: Can you provide some examples? Thks