# In which cases do we need protected inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance

It is clear about public and private inheritance, but what about protected? Any example when we really need to use it and it gives us benefit?

Comment: `giveы`: Hello from Russia :)

Comment: Related: [protected inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090661/protected-inheritance)

Comment: Not every part of C++ is useful. It is natural to *define* a feature like protected inheritance, since it fits neatly into the general scheme, but that doesn't make it widely (or at all) useful. Even some things that *were* explicitly designed turned out not to be useful, like `valarray`, `export`, `vector<bool>` or exception specifications.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Effective C++: discouraging protected inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484306/effective-c-discouraging-protected-inheritance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base-from-member idiom needs protected inheritance at times.

The problem that idiom addresses is the following: you sometimes need to initialize the base class with a member of the derived class, like in

```
struct foo
{
    virtual ~foo() {}

protected:
    foo(std::ostream& os)
    {
        os << "Hello !\n";
    }
};

struct bar : foo
{
    bar(const char* filename)
      : foo(file), file(filename) // Bad, file is used uninitialized
    {}

private:
    std::fstream file;
};
```

But `file` is constructed *after* `foo`, and thus the `ostream` passed to `foo::foo` is invalid.

You solve this with an auxiliary class and private inheritance:

```
struct bar_base
{
    std::fstream file;

protected:
    bar_base(const char* filename) 
      : file(filename) 
    {}   

    ~bar_base() {}
};

struct bar : private bar_base, public foo
{
    bar(const char* filename)
      : bar_base(filename), foo(file)
    {}
};
```

Now `bar_base` is constructed before `foo`, and the `ostream` passed to `foo::foo` is valid.

If you want `file` to become a protected member of `bar`, you must use protected inheritance:

```
struct bar : protected bar_base, public foo { ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

> Protected inheritance is something whose meaning eludes me to this day.

This is Scott Meyers opinion (Effective C++, 3rd Edition) on protected inheritance :).

However, this page is interesting: [Effective C++: discouraging protected inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484306/effective-c-discouraging-protected-inheritance).

Answer (score 2):

`protected` means that the member variables will be accessible from subclasses but not from outside.

A very simple example may be a class that uses a variable (say `x`) to do some internal computation. If a subclass will need to do the same computation will probably need to access `x`. Making it private will avoid the subclass to access it, making it public will make it accessible to everyone. Protected is like a tradeoff.

Comment: The question  is about protected inheritance, `class a : protected b`, not about protected members.

Answer (score 0):

Protected is particularly useful to abstract superclasses, written with knowledge of the children in mind.  Protected members and methods are available to the children, and can save code replication, without exposing them to the world outside the family of classes being implemented at the time.

Comment: The question  is about protected inheritance, `class a : protected b`, not about protected members.